# Why does string stream operator<< erases the original value

Tags: c++

Can someone explain why the following code produce " you!" instead of "hello you!".

```
int main() {
    std::stringstream ss("hello");
    ss << " you!";
    cout << ss.str() << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**openmode** must have `ate` set.

This is what you're looking for:

```
int main() {
    std::stringstream ss("hello", std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::ate);
    ss << " you!";
    cout << ss.str() << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The `std::stringstream` [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/basic_stringstream) taking a `string` parameter is

```
explicit basic_stringstream( const std::basic_string<CharT,Traits,Allocator>& str,
                ios_base::openmode mode = ios_base::in|ios_base::out );
```

Since you haven't specified any flags for `mode`, the underlying stringbuf will be initialized with `ios_base::in|ios_base::out`.

The [stringbuf constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringbuf/basic_stringbuf) taking a string will initialize the internal pointers by calling [`str`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringbuf/str), as you can see in the description if `mode & ios_base::ate` is false then any output will be written to the start of the buffer.

If you want output to be appended to a `stringstream` you will either need to seek to the end before writing, or construct the `stringstream` with `ios_base::in|ios_base::out|ios_base::ate`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It's hard to choose an answer. They are all correct. So i picked the one came on first.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following minor variation of what you wrote and it might be more clear:

```
int main() {
  std::stringstream ss("hello");
  ss << " you";
  cout << ss.str() << endl;
}
```

[Output](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2e58b181fde60ca2): `youo`

When you initialize a `std::stringstream` with a `std::string`, that string becomes the streambuffer. However, the head of the stringstream is initialized at the *beginning* not at the end. In the version where you only write 4 characters instead of 5, the `o` in hello is not overwritten, so you get `youo` as the final value of the buffer.

This behavior is why this code [prints](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/658e7ed6a392ee88) `hello` and not nothing:

```
int main()
{
  std::stringstream ss("hello");
  std::string s;
  ss >> s;
  cout << s << endl;
}
```

This is also why this code [successfully prints](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f2fcac6a8fbdeece) `49` and not nothing:

```
int main()
{
  std::stringstream ss("49");
  int x = 0;
  ss >> x;
  cout << x << endl;
}
```

If you use `ostream::seekp` you can set the position to the end after initialization, so it will do [like you expected](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e4fb700d9f174087):

```
int main() {
  std::stringstream ss("hello");
  ss.seekp(0, ss.end);
  ss << " you!";
  cout << ss.str() << endl;
}
```

Output: `hello you!`